# Add/Remove hyphens/dashes from list of specific words with REGEX (American vs British English)

Tags: .net, regex, list, backreference

I am trying to add/remove hyphens from a list of very specific words in document, e.g.:

afore-mention, base-line, start-up >>
aforemention, baseline, startup

I would like to write ONE REGEX line for this, as the task and pattern is ALWAYS the same: add/remove a hyphen from a known word-pair. Of course, I can do this using a separate REGEX operation for each pair, but this is very clumsy and resource intensive:

```
(afore)-(mention) >> $1$2
(base)-(line) >> $1$2
(start)-(up) >> $1$2
etc.
```

This seems a much simpler approach:

```
(?:(afore)-(mention)|(base)-(line)|(start)-(up))    >> $1$2
```

The problem is that this gives a new back reference for every match, which is not useful. I could make two lists, but then I will have weird matches that I don't want, which becomes a problem if the list gets long, and random matches might occur (afore-line >> aforeline, base-up >> baseup, etc.):

```
(?:(afore|base|start)-(mentioned|line|up))  >> $1$2
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could also match the words and in the replacement, remove the hyphen `\b(?:afore-mention|base-line|start-up)\b` That way you don't have to deal with the capturing groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [named capturing groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named_matched_subexpression) using the `(?<s>...)` or `(?'s'...)` syntax:

```
(?<s>afore)-(?<r>mention)|(?<s>base)-(?<r>line)|(?<s>start)-(?<r>up)
```

Or, to match whole words only, add word boundaries:

```
\b(?:(?<s>afore)-(?<r>mention)|(?<s>base)-(?<r>line)|(?<s>start)-(?<r>up))\b
```

Replace with `${s}${r}`.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3Cs%3Eafore%29-%28%3F%3Cr%3Emention%29%7C%28%3F%3Cs%3Ebase%29-%28%3F%3Cr%3Eline%29%7C%28%3F%3Cs%3Estart%29-%28%3F%3Cr%3Eup%29&i=afore-mention%2C%20base-line%2C%20start-up%20%0D%0Aafore-line%20%20base-up&r=%24%7Bs%7D%24%7Br%7D).

Any part before the hyphen will land in the `s` named capture, and the second part will be in Group `r`. The named backreference syntax in .NET regex is

```
${name}
```

Demo screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this great and fast explanation. I learned something very useful here, that I am sure will help ion other situations as well. Cheers!